# R: Removing Non-Corresponding Rows in Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two data frames - `germany_yields` and `italy_yields`. If a specific date that appears in one of `germany_yields`'s rows is not present in any of `italy_yields`'s rows, then I would like to remove this row from `germany_yields` (and vice versa).

For example, here are five rows taken from either of the frames:

```
germany_yields:                        italy_yields:

            Date Yield                             Date Yield        
642 Jan 06, 2008 4.087                 642 Jan 06, 2008 4.461
643 Dec 30, 2007 4.193                 643 Dec 30, 2007 4.522
644 Dec 23, 2007 4.368                 644 Dec 16, 2007 4.563
645 Dec 16, 2007 4.268                 645 Dec 09, 2007 4.601        
646 Dec 09, 2007 4.304                 646 Dec 02, 2007 4.420
647 Dec 02, 2007 4.105                 647 Nov 25, 2007 4.439
```

The date Dec 23, 2007 is present within `germany_yields` (row 644), but not within `italy_yields`. I would therefore like to remove row 644 from `germany_yields`. How can I do this?

For reference, here is the code I have so far:

```
germany_yields <- read.csv(file = "Germany 10-Year Yield Weekly (2007-2020).csv")
italy_yields <- read.csv(file = "Italy 10-Year Yield Weekly (2007-2020).csv")

germany_yields <- germany_yields[, -(3:6)]
italy_yields <- italy_yields[, -(3:6)]

colnames(germany_yields)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(germany_yields)[2] <- "Yield"
colnames(italy_yields)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(italy_yields)[2] <- "Yield"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to use `%in%`:

```r
germany_yields[germany_yields$Date %in% italy_yields$Date, ]
```

Comment: The first option (%in%) works fine, but the second (merge) messes up the frame by jumbling all of the dates up.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
germany_yields %>%
      filter(Date %in% italy_yields$Date)
```